# jQuery How to disable mobile scrolling then enable it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I was able to disable it like this

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
$(document).bind('touchmove', false);
});
```

But I want to enable it again when I click on another div, I tried:

```
$('#div2').click(function(){
$(document).bind('touchmove', true);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've never used this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#div2').click(function(){
     $(document).unbind('touchmove');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was simple! Learning